# Extract specific elements from an input file and write them to an output file using StAX

Tags: xml, tags, extract, element, stax

Let say that I have the next XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
     <order created='2002-02-12T11:10:30.000' ID='1233'>
          <fruit>
               <description>Red apples</description>
               <price currency="USD">13.25</price>
               <gardener>John</gardener>
          <fruit>
          <fruit>
               <description>Bananas</description>
               <price currency="USD">11.19</price>
               <gardener>Ana</gardener>
          <fruit>
          <fruit>
               <description>Golden apples</description>
               <price currency="USD">16.46</price>
               <gardener>John</gardener>
          <fruit>
     </order>
     <order created='2002-02-13T15:32:30.000' ID='1234'>
          <fruit>
               <description>Oranges</description>
               <price currency="USD">10.99</price>
               <gardener>Ana</gardener>
          <fruit>
          <fruit>
               <description>Kiwi</description>
               <price currency="USD">10.39</price>
               <gardener>Helen</gardener>
          <fruit>
     </order>
</orders>
```

And I need to write one XML file for each distinct gradener. (John, Ana, Helen).
The name of the xml file should be like gradener_name## where ## are first 2 digits from the value of ID attribute in "order" element (ex. Ana12).
Ex. Ana12.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fruits>
     <fruit>
          <description>Bananas</description>
          <price currency="USD">11.19</price>
          <gardener>Ana</gardener>
     <fruit>
     <fruit>
          <description>Oranges</description>
          <price currency="USD">10.99</price>
          <gardener>Ana</gardener>
     <fruit>
</fruits>
```

Here, the fruits are sorted by price. First fruit is the one with higher price.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in 2 steps:

1. Read you XML with a `XMLInputFactory` and `XMLStreamReader` for instance. While reading the XML you create your own model representation (up to you to create a gardener_name## equivalent model)
2. After this XML reading you must have an collection of 3 Gardener object or whatever object you created, create a new XML file and generate the content you want with `XMLOutputFactory` and `XMLStreamWriter` for instance.

Having your own model will make it easy to sort fruits by price. I don't think it is a good approach to try to do this without creating your custom intermediate java model.

**EDIT :**
As additional comment to your other questions: don't try to read and write at the same time. Your logic needs java object representation, you cannot do what you want only by reacting to events.